# Windows 10 Tablet stuck at Startup Repair

Tags: windows-10, boot, tablet

I've got an RCA (Cambio W101SA23T1) 2-in-1 Windows 10 tablet and a few days back I powered it to just to be taken to the Startup Repair screen.
It's asking for my password and because I've always been logging in using the PIN (I've forgotten my password)
Selecting the Forgot Password option, asks me to reboot but again I'm brought back to the StartUp Repair.

I went online and changed my password but the new password does not seem to be connecting to this tablet (maybe a local a/c on the tablet)

I've tried starting up pressing F9 (as per RCA's troubleshooting website) but no luck. Just being brought back to Startup Repair.

I've written to RCA but no response.

What can I do?

Comment: Sometimes startup repair has to run several times before it will boot properly

Comment: or see this>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-10-automatic-repair-loop/1d7c05b1-e424-46dc-97b9-13f1dfcdc8b1

Comment: Since the problem started a few days back, I must have restarted close to a hundred times. The issue I'm facing is, how to get in with a forgotten password.

Comment: I **can** access the BIOS. Would there be any ways there to maybe reset or even reinstall Windows 10 afresh? The device does have an SD-Card slot. Here's some snapshots of the BIOS [link]{https://link.shutterfly.com/0NFeuqJASab} 
I really need to bypass this automatic startup repair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled to get a solution and in doing, was guided to [INSTALL LINUX on an RCA Cambio! IT IS POSSIBLE!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuOXEJO9wm4)
Here I saw that someone had actually managed to install Linux on this particular tablet and he's been very kind to share his experiences and challenges and so have others who have posted therein.
Using this method, I succeeded in booting the device using a Linux Mint LXDE USB and from there I used the CHNTPW method to remove the forgotten Windows 10 password.
Thereafter when I rebooted the device and was brought back to Startup Repair, I was now not required to put in a password and thereafter successfully reset the device.

ALHAMDULILLAH.